# CSS keyframe of display attribute not working

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I have a div element which I want to slide in from the bottom of the screen.
The following CSS works, however. the div takes up space, so the vertical scroll bar is visible.

**How can I make this div element slide in and out (from the bottom) via this CSS keyframe without showing the scroll bar?**

I tried using display: none on the div, and setting display: block in the keyframes, but that didn't work at all (the div remains display: none). CSS keyframes doesn't seem to work on display attribute.

CSS for div with animationIn class:

```
div.animateIn {
    -webkit-animation-name: slideIn; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: slideIn;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

CSS keyframe to slide in:

```
@keyframes slideIn {
0% {
    top: 100vh;
    display: block;
}

100% {
    top: 25vh;
    display: block;
}
}
```

Comment: overflow:hidden on the container

Comment: If the element has position: fixed it shouldn't influence the overflow, and it sounds like you'll end up wanting that to keep it locked at the bottom of the screen anyways